# wrong memory allocation new char [n]

Tags: c++, memory, allocation

What is wrong with this program?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void main()
{

    int n = 5;
    char* p = new char [n];
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        p[i] = 'A'+i;
    }
    cout<<p<<endl;
}
```

Why do I get "ABCDExxxx" instead of "ABCDE" ?
What is wrong with memory allocation?

Comment: Please use `std::string` in C++. If you need a `char*` just call the `c_str()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can allocate the storage for `char` using `new` this way, it is OK. However if you are going to use it later with functions that relates on null terminating character (like `strlen` i.e, or printing this out) then when allocating the storage for a `char*` you need to allocate the number of characters **+ 1** more to store the `\0`. C Strings need to be null-terminated.

> Why do I get "ABCDExxxx" instead of "ABCDE" ? What is wrong with
>   memory allocation?

your data is not null terminated (doesn't contain `'\0'` at the end so you are printing garbages until character `'\0'` is found somewhere else). To make it work as expected you can do:

```
int n = 5;
char* p = new char [n+1];
p[n]='\0';

for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    p[i] = 'A'+i;
         ^
        side note: this is OK, however if your p has been pointing to a string 
        literal, i.e. if it was defined as  char*p = "string literal\n";
        then according to section 2.14.5 paragraph 11 of the C++ standard,
        it would invoke undefined behavior:
        The effect of attempting to modify a string literal is undefined.
        so be aware :p !

}
cout<<p<<endl;
```

remember  then to deallocate storage with

`delete [] p;`

and as others commented, it might be a better idea to use `std::string` instead.

Answer (score 5):

There's nothing wrong with the memory allocation, except that the memory is never released. Don't forget to `delete [] p;` before `main` returns.

The problem with the output is that the string that `p` points to does not have a terminating `'\0'`. In general, you should allocate an array with room for at least one more character than you're going to put into the array, and put a `'\0'` after the last one. Of course, a better solution is to use `std::string`, which takes care of all that for you.

Answer (score 2):

C Strings need to be null-terminated.  Add one more byte containing 0.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, **please** don't use C style when you're already on C++

Use `std::string` instead

It has a member function `c_str()` that helps to work with C api/functions

---

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
^^ main should return int
{

    int n = 5;
   //C string needs to be null terminated, so an extra
    char* p = new char [n+1];
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        p[i] = 'A'+i;
    }
    p[i] = '\0'; //Insert the null character
    cout<<p<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are simply not putting a null character. Use this code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void main()
{

    int n = 5;
    char* p = new char [n];
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        p[i] = 'A'+i;
    }
    cout<<p<<endl;
}
```

As you are using c++ i recomend using `std::string`.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
        using namespace std;
        void main()
        {

            //int n = 5;
            //char* p = new char [n];
            string s;
            int i;
            for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            {
                s.append("/*whatever string you want to append*/");
            }
            cout<<s<<endl;
        }
```

Comment: "/*whatever you want to append*/" format might be "whatever you want to append" I think

Answer (score 0):

when the endl met '\0' ,it return,so if you dont have a '\0' in the char[],until found it,it will continue  to read memoery.

Comment: `endl` has nothing to do with this